# How to Transfer/Migrate data from SQL Server 2008 to ORACLE 11g?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

Hello guys I have Tables , Views , Stored Procedure in my sql server and now I want to transfer it in Oracle but I don't how to do it. Is there any tools that I can use?. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLServerMigration/SQLServerMigration.htm)??

Comment: Not yet but I will try to use this tool.

Comment: @geeky I am getting an error in Migrating.

Comment: What error you are getting and at which step?

Comment: @Geeky: First I can't create a connection using "orcl" SID. BTW geeky I am using v4.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. We (Oracle Corp) give you [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/index-084442.html) which includes a full database migration kit, including T-SQL translators which will move your code into Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: I will try your suggestion.